# Turning string WITH (react-native) TAGS into map'able / outputable object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently facing a challenge where I have to use an API that responses with pure HTML like this:

```
<div class="yx"><h3>SomeHead</h3><div class="otherclass"><p>someText</p></div><span class="time">23123123</span></div><div class="yx"><h3>SomeHead</h3><div class="otherclass"><p>someText</p></div><span class="time">23123123</span></div><div class="yx"><h3>SomeHead</h3><div class="otherclass"><p>someText</p></div><span class="time">23123123</span></div>
```

Since I need to display this information in my native app I had to replace all HTML syntax with native one.
After trying around with some self written functions I have managed to obtain a seemingly correct method which transforms everything into following output: (array)

```
0: "<View><Text>SomeHead</Text><View><Text>someText</Text></View><Text>41234123</Text></View>"
1: "<View><Text>SomeHead</Text><View><Text>someText</Text></View><Text>41234123</Text></View>"
3: "<View><Text>SomeHead</Text><View><Text>someText</Text></View><Text>41234123</Text></View>"
```

Now I need to somehow manage to output that string with the correct syntax into my application - unfortunately I am yet struggling to find a proper solution.

`JSON.` methods don't work since they can only deal with JSON syntax and `<` is not in their support range

**Note** the content of the response is not the actual content, but it represents my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading and blindly integrating data from a third party API right?

Never, ever, trust data from a source that is not under your complete control.

The best way imho is to load the data, put it into an HTML parser and then extract the data you want, escape it (!) and programmatically create your JSX.